# Change connection string in EF6 based on provider from config

Tags: c#, orm, entity-framework-6

I have moved to EntityFramework 6 from EF5.

Now I am facing an issue, I want to change the connection string based the provider set in app.Config.
Meaning If it is SqlServerCe, then I need to change the DatabaseFile.sdf file name to change a database. 
If it is SqlServer, the I need to change InitialCataloge.

I did this by getting the type of

'Database.DefaultConnectionFactory' but this is Obsolete in EF6.

How can I modify the connection string based on provider.

I cannot do this by using DbConfiguration Attribute since I need to modify connection string everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new YourDbConfiguration());
```

so you can use your config without using an attribute.

But if I use

```
public CeDbConfiguration()
{
 SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SqlCeConnectionFactory(SqlCeProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName,
                                                        @"c:\test",
                                                        @"c:\test\db.sdf"));
SetProviderServices(SqlCeProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName,
                    SqlCeProviderServices.Instance);
}
```

to to configure a SQL CE Factory, the path *'C:\test'* will be ignored an I have to set Database.DefaultConnectionFactory also!!